# application stops working when set to background

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

The code works fine when the window is open in the foreground and when I press the space key, the mouse moves as expected, but as soon as I move to another application and I press the space key, the mouse no longer moves as expected with the keystroke, How do I keep the application working even when it is set to the background

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {       
    var timer: Timer!       
    @objc func movethemouse() {       
        let mouseLocx = NSEvent.mouseLocation.x       
        let mouseLocy = NSEvent.mouseLocation.y       
        let screenH = NSScreen.main?.frame.height       
        let deltaX = CGFloat(Int(1))       
        let deltaY = CGFloat(Int(1))       
        let newLoc = CGPoint(x: mouseLocx + deltaX , y: screenH! - mouseLocy - deltaY )       
        CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGMainDisplayID(), newLoc)
    }       
    override func viewDidLoad() {       
        super.viewDidLoad()       
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.       
    }       
    override func viewDidAppear() {       
        view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self)       
    }       
    override var acceptsFirstResponder : Bool {       
        return true       
    }       
    var count3=0       
    var flag = false       
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {       
        if (event.keyCode == 49){       
            flag = true       
            if count3 == 0 {       
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target:self, selector: #selector(ViewController.movethemouse), userInfo: nil, repeats:true)       
            print(event)       
            }       
           count3 += 1       
        }       
    }       
    override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {       
        print(event)       
        if (event.keyCode == 49) {       
            if flag {       
                timer.invalidate()       
                count3 = 0       
                print(event)       
            }       
        }       
    }       
}
```

Comment: I think your App gets no events because the other App is in the foreground already handles the keyboard events. Have you added some logging to see whether your `keyDown` and `keyUp` are actually called?

Comment: The events KeyDown and KeyUp are no longer called once the app is in the background. That is what am trying to solve, how do I keep them active while the application is running in the background.

Comment: Key and mouse events go to the frontmost app. Read [Monitoring Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH15-SW3) in [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture system wide events. Here's some sample code that will get everything in the system. Note that you have to enable assistive mode for XCode (during development) or your app (running outside XCode) for this to work.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    if getAccessibility() {
        snarfKeys()
    }
    // etc...
}

func getAccessibility() -> Bool {
    let trusted = AXIsProcessTrusted()
    if !trusted {
        print("process is not trusted")
    }
    return trusted
}

func snarfKeys() {
    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyUp, handler: keyPress)
    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .leftMouseUp, handler: mousePress)
}
```

snarfKeys does the magic, but as noted above and in the code, the process needs to be trusted to be able to add global event monitoring.